# Delete object in OneToOne relationship ConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I'm trying to delete entity which is the owner of the relationship, but I am getting an exception as follows:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint
>   violation: "FKS59BBPCYQ1GUKBWWA61TYF8YF: PUBLIC.RESERVATIONS FOREIGN
>   KEY(CAR_LICENSE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CARS(LICENSE_ID) ('EPA13S')";
>   SQL statement:

I know that is because of trying to delete an object to which another one has a reference with fk_key. Here is my model:

```
public class Reservation
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DriverType driverType;

    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    private LocalDateTime stopTime;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Car car;

    private BigDecimal cost;
}

public class Car
{
    @Id
    @NonNull
    @Size(min = 6, max = 6)
    String licenseId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "car", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    Reservation reservation;
}
```

How could I possibly deal with such scenario? I would like to delete car from parking when the reservation ends as I don't need it and having license id as pk_key make it vulnerable for trying to insert new car with upcoming reservation even though the previous one has ended.

Deleting car:

`carRepository.deleteByLicenseId(reservation.getCarLicenseId());`

`@Query("DELETE FROM Car c where c.licenseId = :licenseId")
  void deleteByLicenseId(@Param("licenseId") String licenseId);`

Comment: Can you please post your code that deletes the Car.

Comment: added at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are extending Spring `CrudRepository<Reservation, Long>`

The joinColumn is on the Reservation side and from what I can see what you want to do is to delete the Reservation as well. So why not delete it from the owning side, which looks like the reservation.

Change Reservation to.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
```

Rather use the following for delete.

```
reservationRepository.delete(reservation);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bidirectional relationship. Add this to `Car` class:

```
public void removeReservation() {
    if (this.reservation != null) {
        this.reservation.setCar(null);
        this.reservation = null;
    }
}
```

Call `car.removeReservation()`.

Then delete car.